# Changing a site-wide banner image with another image?

Tags: html, css, image, banner, squarespace

Kind of new to coding and website building and have a company asking to make them a simple website.  Well I cant just do something simple. [Website link](https://panda-megalodon-4ak4.squarespace.com).  Not my choice on using SS.  So the banner image is set to default for the whole website.  All I want to do is pick a couple of pages and override the image and keep the fixed position effect.  Here is the code I am trying:

```
banner-image: url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5b8838fbe74940afd72fe383/t/5bd0af80f4e1fc41dabbc23c/1540403072779/Oil-Field.jpg") !important;
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: You should post your html, css instead of linking to a site, that might change.

Comment: I've not used Squarespace, so I'm no expert, but the code there is a line that says `<!-- // page thumbnail image as banner image -->` My guess is that the image on each page is determined by the selection of a thumbnail image for that page, and potentially a fallback one is already specified in case none is selected, and that is what you are seeing here.